# length() of string is returning 0 for a C++ program

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, reverse

In the following code the length of the reversed string is being returned as zero which should not be the case:

```
int main() {

string for_reversal;
string reversed;
int i,j,length, r_length;

cout << "Enter the string : \n";
cin >> for_reversal;
cout << "Entered string is :  " << for_reversal <<"\n";
cout << "String length is :  " << for_reversal.length() << "\n";
length = for_reversal.length();

for (i=0; i<=length; i++)
{
    reversed[i] = for_reversal[length - i-1];
    cout << for_reversal[length-i] << "\t";

}


reversed[length+1]='\0';
cout << "\n";

r_length = reversed.length();
cout << "Reversed String length is : " << r_length << "\n";
cout << "Reversed String is : " << reversed;

return 0;
}
```

Not sure whats going wrong here.

Comment: Where do you initialize `reserved`??? You should by the least do `reserved.reserve(length+1)` before that `for` loop. BTW, you could simply use `push_back` instead of `[i]`.

Comment: You are never actually growing the size of `reversed`, just writing into some unknown memory that happens to live next to `reversed`.

Comment: You aren't resizing the `reversed` string; `reversed.resize(for_reversal.length());` before reversing the string...

Comment: I suggest you start using `at` instead of `[]` when first working with the standard library.  It will help to catch these mistakes.  `reversed.at(i)` would have shown you where the problem is.

Comment: Adding  `reversed.resize(for_reversal.length()); ` works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are `length` valid characters in a string with length `length`. In your cycle you access the element with index `length` which is out of bounds for the string and this invokes **undefined behavior**.

Additionally you can not assign values to cells in a string that are outside of its current size, while you assign values to the cells in `reversed` before resizing the string appropriately. This leads to second **undefined behavior**.

Having in mind the two issues I mentioned above the behavior of your problem is really not defined. However the output does makes sense if we ignore that -  you assign to reversed[0] the value of `for_reversal[length]`, which is probably `'\0'`. As a result the length of `reversed` is now 0.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
reversed[i] = for_reversal[length - i-1];
```

to

```
reversed+=for_reversal[length - i-1];
```

The way you're doing it is accessing the string out of its bound, paving the way for all kinds of hell breaking through. They way proposed above will append stuff to the string, reserving space as needed.

You could try and reserve space in "reversed" (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) so it can hold the original string (reversed.reserve(for_reversal.size())).

In any case, please not that you're not reserving space for the \0 character. Either reserve a bigger string or append \0 with the + operator.

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior because the string `reversed` is empty

```
string reversed;
```

and you may not use the subscript operator

```
reversed[i] = for_reversal[length - i-1];
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to assign values to the string.

Also there is no need to append the zero character to objects of type `std::string`.

Take into account that in the loop

```
for (i=0; i<=length; i++)
{
    reversed[i] = for_reversal[length - i-1];
    cout << for_reversal[length-i] << "\t";

}
```

then `i` is equal to `length` then you will have

```
reversed[length] = for_reversal[-1];
                               ^^^^^
```

The simplest way to create a reversed string is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string for_reversal;

    std::cout << "Enter the string: ";
    std::cin >> for_reversal;

    std::string reversed( for_reversal.rbegin(), for_reversal.rend() );

    std::cout << "\nReversed String length is : " << reversed.length() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Reversed String is : " << reversed << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Enter the string: Hello

Reversed String length is : 5
Reversed String is : olleH
```

If you want to write the loop yourself then you should reserve enough memory in the reversed string or at least use member function `push_back` instead of the subscript operator if the string initially is empty. The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string for_reversal;
    std::string reversed;

    std::cout << "Enter the string: ";
    std::cin >> for_reversal;

    reversed.reserve( for_reversal.length() );

    for ( std::string::size_type i = for_reversal.length(); i != 0; i-- )
    {
        reversed += for_reversal[i-1];
    }

    std::cout << "\nReversed String length is : " << reversed.length() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Reversed String is : " << reversed << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above

```
Enter the string: Hello

Reversed String length is : 5
Reversed String is : olleH
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
  reversed[i] = for_reversal[length - i-1];
  // ...
}
```

With the statement:

```
reversed[i]
```

You're actually trying to access the *i-th* element of the string, with *i=0, 1, ..., length*.

But at that moment, the object string `reversed` is an *empty string*. Indeed you've created it with:

```
string reversed;
```

That is *default constructor* which initializes an *empty* string.

In other words, `reversed[i]` access to *undefined* memory location, since `reversed` is void, and there is no *i-th* position in the string.

---

## Solution

In order to reverse a string you may find this code useful:

```
std::string reversed;

for(auto rit = for_reversal.rbegin(); rit != for_reversal.rend(); ++rit) {
  reversed.push_back(*rit);
}
```

This code should be safer that your, using *iterators* (in that case [reversed iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/)).

#### Note

Moreover there is no need to append the `'\0'` char at the end, because the class `string` already handles that.

Answer (score 0):

```
first initialize string reversed with empty string i.e string reversed="";
after this change for loop:
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
   reversed+=for_reversal[length-1-i];
   cout << for_reversal[length-i] << endl;
}
int r_length=reversed.length();
cout << "reversed string length : " << r_length << endl;
cout << "Reversed string is : " << reversed << endl;
```

hope u understand.